# Iteratively formatting the specific parts of a String in Java

Tags: java, string, format

I know that in java we can do something like:

```
String s = "I am a %s %s"

s = s.format("format", "string")
```

I was wondering if it is possible to replace the occurance of only one`%s` at a time and furthermore if I can give names to these such as `%1` , `%2`. What I am trying to achieve is having a huge html string where each method will complete a specific part of that string. The string will be completed in an iterative way and I want to make sure that each method completes its own part.

Comment: Don't do that.  You'll end up creating a giant mess and an XSS vulnerability.  Instead, use an HTML templating engine.

Comment: I am not sure if I can use that since I am on Blackberry platform. What I really want is to create an html document and then email it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically, you can use simply `String.replace`:

```
s = s.replace("%1", value1);
s = s.replace("%2", value2);
```

Depending on what you want to do, you may or may not have to think about security and people using this to inject malicious scripts in your html. In the latter case, sanitizing the user input is top priority.